# Elasticsearch geo_point mapping type overwritten on first save

Tags: elasticsearch

*I realise mapping types are being removed in 7.x but I am working with a solution that uses 6.x.*

I have an index I am creating which has a location property. When creating the index I add the following mapping property:

```
mappings: {
 _doc: {
  properties: {
     location: {
         type: 'geo_point'
       }
     }
  }
}
```

There are other properties that will be in the index but I'm happy for those to be defined automatically (I presume I can do that as elsewhere in the application it has been done this way with no problems).

The index is created ok but when I index my first entity and run a query using the location field I get the following error: `failed to find geo_point field [location]`

Looking at the mappings now defined in ElasticSearch I can see my location field has now become an object with two float values instead of a `geo_point`:

```
{"job-posts":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"_doc":{"properties":{"location":{"properties":{"lat":{"type":"float"},"lon":{"type":"float"}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1591636220162","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"qwAybNlFQ4i3q7IecdZFvA","version":{"created":"6040099"},"provided_name":"job-posts"}}}}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong and why my mapping is being overwritten?

**Updated**
Right after I create the index the mapping looks like this:
`{"job-posts":{"mappings":{"_doc":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point"}}}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to include `properties`:

```
PUT myindex?include_type_name=true
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If that doesn't help, what's the index mapping right after you create the index but before you sync the first doc?

Comment: Thanks Joe, that was my mistake copying the code. I've now updated the question with the index mapping right after I create the index.

Comment: Thanks. What does your doc look like?

Comment: I've just realised that my initial index creation code with the mapping wasn't actually being run, I assumed it was because the index was created and a document was placed into it but it seems ES will create the index if you POST a document to a named index that doesn't exist yet. Appreciate you taking the time to look into it anyway

Comment: That's right. It'll create a (guessed) mapping which is exactly what happened. No problem.